# an error in XML document

Tags: xml

I need some help badly. I cannot open a project file (.mpr) in one of Computer Aided Translation programmes (an error in XML document). It says as follows:

```
TYPE:
System.InvalidOperationException

MESSAGE:
There is an error in XML document (102, 3).

SOURCE:
System.Xml

CALL STACK:
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
   at Kilgray.Utils.SerializationHelper.DeserializeXML(Type objType, String filePath)
   at MemoQ.Project.Migration.ProjectMigrator.PerformV5toV6Migration(Form owner, String& projectDirectory)
   at MemoQ.Project.ProjectDocument.OnOpenDocument(Object openParam)
   at MemoQ.ApplicationFramework.DocTypeManager.<>c__DisplayClass7.<OpenDocument>b__6()
   at MemoQ.ApplicationFramework.DocTypeManager.executeFromOpenErrorHandlingBlock(Func`1 func, Object openParam)
------------------ Inner exception ------------------

TYPE:
System.Xml.XmlException

MESSAGE:
'', hexadecimal value 0x04, is an invalid character. Line 102, position 3.

SOURCE:
System.Xml

CALL STACK:
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Int32 pos, Char invChar)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.UnknownNode(Object o, String qnames)
   at 
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderProjectInfo.Read44_ProjectInfo(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderProjectInfo.Read45_ProjectInfo()
```

Comment: The XML is not valid so you need to edit the file or recreate it. The program that produced it has a bug

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the first 120 lines of your XML file?